# Java ActionListener On Main Method

Tags: java, actionlistener

I have created a java class in which I have used one frame one panel two textbox and two labels with one button but the Jbutton actionListener Is Not Working Please help I am trying for more than one hour but it is not working with the graphical using interface using javax.swing

```
public class GuiBasics {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public GuiBasics(){
        int count=0;

        JFrame jf=new JFrame("Gui Basics");
        JPanel jp=new JPanel();
        JLabel jl1=new JLabel("Username");
        JLabel jl2=new JLabel("Password");

        JTextField jt1=new JTextField(20);
        JTextField jt2=new JTextField(20);
        jp.add(jl1);
        jp.add(jt1);
        jp.add(jl2);
        jp.add(jt2);
        jp.add(jb);
        jf.add(jp);
        jf.setSize(400, 600);
        jf.setVisible(true);

        JButton button = new JButton("Click");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             System.out.println("Checking!");
          }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GuiBasics();
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't add the button to your gui

Comment: you are not adding your button to your gui

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the button to your JPanel like you did for your other widget components.

Code should be:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click");
jp.add(button);
```

And you should see & will be able to click your button